# Identifying features using ArcGIS Engine?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, identify

I am new to arcgis.

I am building a custom desktop GIS application using arcgis engine 9.3.1 .

I want to make a custom identify tool and add it to toolbar control.

Any example or code will be helpfull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ESRI web site ([link](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/Samples/Controls/Commands/Identify/Identify.htm)) provides various versions of the identify command (code samples in VB) that you may use as a starting template for your custom tool.

Comment: Thanx for the link.Its very usefull info.thanx again brother..

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for the same sort of information, but for newer versions, VBA support is being discontinued in versions newer than 10.

See http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/conceptualhelp/index.html#/what_s_new_at_10_/000100000133000000/

> **Important Deprecation Notice for VBA users**
>
> ESRI will no longer support VBA as a development platform beyond ArcGIS 10. Users who have custom functionality built using VBA are strongly encouraged to rewrite it using a supported development language such as Python, VB.NET, or C# to ensure that it continues to be operational and supported with future releases of ArcGIS.  The topic Migrating VBA customizations to ArcGIS 10 provides some guidance.