# How to create custom Identify tool for ArcMap and ArcExplorer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, identify, arcgis-explorer

I need to create an identify tool that will return text attributes arranged in a graphical form. The scenario is there are text attributes for signs and they need to be displayed just like they would on the sign that is identified (like a graphic). This would also need to be used in ArcExplorer for those in my department with and without ArcMap 10.

Comment: Isn't this the same question as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8638/identify-features?

Comment: -1. I don't see what kind of answer you're expecting, your question doesn't state the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by using an HTMl link for each feature on the map (in this case, points for intersections). PDF were liked via the HTML popup feature in ArcMap 10 which provided the original information for each feature, reducing the probability of data entry error.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no particular reason why you want to create your own Identify tool, then I think it would work to just:

- [Use the "HTML pop-ups" tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Using_HTML_pop_ups_for_feature_layers/00s500000018000000/) or
- [Use Hyperlinks within your attribute table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000004000000.htm) or
- [Add raster datasets as attributes in a feature class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t000001np000000) to your database.

Comment: The goal is to create a popup that displays attribute data in a certain layout. After more research, it looks like I may be able to solve the problem using an HTML popup.

Comment: Did you ever resolve your question? Feel free to post it as an answer. Nothing wrong with answering your own question!

Comment: Yup, solved it using an HTML popup that linked to a PDF. The scenario was I needed to link official printed data to a map and linking to a scanned PDF worked perfectly.

Comment: @Matt, could you please "Answer" your own question with some added details about your solution and check it as the "Accpeted" answer so others can learn from your work?